# Custom WebComponent doesn't show inherited properties from parent

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, firefox-addon, web-component, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created a custom WebComponent named `search-window` that extends HTMLElement for my Firefox addon. What I've noticed is that when I `console.log( document.getElementByTagName('search-window') )` I don't see the properties inherited from the Parent and the prototype shows as restricted(check screenshot below).

[image]

Inside my class definition I can access all the properties using eg. `this.offsetLeft` but if I `console.log(this)` shows the same info as I mentioned before(check screenshot below).

[image]

---

A simplified version of my code:

`SearchWindow.js`

```
export default class SearchWindow extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this)
    }
}
```

`entry.js`

```
import SearchWindow from './SearchWindow.js';
import '../../assets/scss/main.scss'

customElements.define( 'search-window', SearchWindow );
```

---

I've tried executing the same code inside the console and I could see and access every property inherited from `HTMLElement`. Why does this happen?

Comment: Is this inside the content script? They run in isolated world so the main page can't access its JS artifacts like objects or methods unless you explicitly [expose them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) via `exportFunction` and `cloneInto`.

Comment: Yes, it's inside the content scripts. How would I approach this in my case to export the element's properties? I am not sure I understand how to achieve this from the documentation.

Comment: Why creating a dependency? Why don't you ``customElements.define()`` in SearchWindow.js ??

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yeah I guess I could keep everything related to `search-window` inside `SearchWindow.js` but `entry.js` also has code related to the context menu so I preferred to keep them separately.